# Zxing causes app to stop&exit

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to add zxing as library to my android app - it must be offline so using Intent to outside app is bad as many people wouldn't have bar code scanner.
I have Zxing as library, name is "zxingLib", and in my app "IntentIntegrator" and "IntentResult" + core.jar added.

In my app I call zxing by button:

```
public void scanNow(View view){

    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}
```

and to obtain result:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
      IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      if (scanResult != null) {
          intent.putExtra("com.tajchert.kolejrogowska.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
          String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
          String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Content:" + contents + " Format:" + format , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
          toast.show();
      }
    }
```

After pressing it show messege to install Barcode reader (form google play) - what I'm doing wrong?
But If I already have barcode on my phone it stop (app&barcode reader).
Log cat:

```
11-15 14:26:50.132: I/Process(29283): Sending signal. PID: 29283 SIG: 9
11-15 14:27:50.194: E/Trace(29345): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-15 14:27:50.202: V/ActivityThread(29345): com.google.zxing.client.android white listed for hwui
11-15 14:27:50.389: I/a(29345): Using implementation class com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.HoneycombAsyncTaskExecInterface of interface com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.AsyncTaskExecInterface for SDK 11
11-15 14:27:50.491: I/a(29345): Using implementation class com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.GingerbreadOpenCameraInterface of interface com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.OpenCameraInterface for SDK 9
11-15 14:27:50.491: I/GingerbreadOpenCamera(29345): Opening camera #0
11-15 14:27:51.116: I/CameraConfiguration(29345): Screen resolution: Point(854, 480)
11-15 14:27:51.116: I/CameraConfiguration(29345): Supported preview sizes: 1280x720 848x480 640x480 352x288 320x240 176x144 
11-15 14:27:51.116: I/CameraConfiguration(29345): Found best approximate preview size: Point(1280, 720)
11-15 14:27:51.116: I/CameraConfiguration(29345): Camera resolution: Point(1280, 720)
11-15 14:27:51.155: I/CameraConfiguration(29345): Initial camera parameters: rotation-values=0,90,180,270;mot-postview-mode=on;zoom=0;mot-video-size=640x480;mot-sensor-display-orientation-support-values=off,on;mot-face-track-frame-skip=15;zoom-supported=true;mot-flip-mode-values=off;whitebalance=auto;mot-face-track-mode=off;scene-mode=auto;jpeg-quality=85;preview-format-values=yuv420sp,yuv422i-yuyv;rotation=0;mot-picture-iso-values=auto;jpeg-thumbnail-quality=75;preview-format=yuv420sp;mot-zoom-step=0.5;mot-sensor-display-orientation=0;video-size-values=;mot-video-stabilization-values=off;mot-image-stabilization-values=off;preview-size=848x480;focal-length=3.92;mot-max-picture-continuous-zoom=6;flash-mode-values=off,on,auto,torch;preview-frame-rate-values=10,15,20,24,25,30;mot-image-stabilization=off;mot-exposure-offset-values=-3,-2.67,-2.33,-2,-1.67,-1.33,-1,-0.67,-0.33,0,0.33,0.67,1,1.33,1.67,2,2.33,2.67,3;preview-frame-rate=24;mot-face-detect-num-faces=4;mot-max-face-detect-num-faces=9;focus-mode-values=auto,macro,infinity,off;jpeg-thumbnail-width=320;scene-mode-values=auto,portrait,landscape,action,night-portrait,sunset,steadyphoto;preview-fps-range-values=(10000,30000),(10000,25000),(10000,20000),(10000,24000),(10000,15000),(10000,10000);mot-face-track-mode-values=off;jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=0x0,320x240;zoom-ratios=100,200,300,400;mot-zoom-speed=50;preview-size-values=176x144,320x240,352x288,640x480,848x480,1280x720;picture-size-values=320x240,640x480,1280x960,1600x1200,2048x1536,2592x1456,2592x1936;preview-fps-range=10000, 30000;min-exposure-compensation=-9;antibanding=auto;mot-video-size-values=176x144,320x240,352x288,640x480;vertical-view-angle=40;horizontal-view-angle=53;mot-sensor-display-orientation-support=off;jpeg-thumbnail-height=240;cam-mode=0;smooth-zoom-supported=false;mot-picture-iso=auto;mot-continuous-zoom-step-values=1,0.5,0.25;max-video-continuous-zoom=6;focus-mode=on;mot-video-stabilization=off;mot-flip-mode=off;mot-sensor-display-orientation-values=0,90;video-frame-format=yuv422i-yuyv;picture-format-values=jpeg;mot-areas-to-focus=0;max-exposure-compensation=9;mot-postview-modes=off,on;exposure-compensation=0;exposure-compensation-step=0.3333333333333;mot-max-areas-to-focus=1;flash-mode=off;effect-values=none,mono,sepia,negative,solarize,red-tint,green-tint,blue-tint;picture-size=2592x1936;mot-timestamp-mode=off;max-zoom=3;effect=none;mot-timestamp-mode-values=off,on;mot-exposure-offset=0;whitebalance-values=auto;picture-format=jpeg;jpeg-thumbnail-size=320x240;antibanding-values=auto
11-15 14:27:51.155: I/CameraConfiguration(29345): Supported values: [off, on, auto, torch]
11-15 14:27:51.155: I/CameraConfiguration(29345): Settable value: off
11-15 14:27:51.155: I/CameraConfiguration(29345): Supported values: [auto, macro, infinity, off]
11-15 14:27:51.155: I/CameraConfiguration(29345): Settable value: auto
11-15 14:27:51.218: I/a(29345): Using implementation class com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.HoneycombAsyncTaskExecInterface of interface com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.AsyncTaskExecInterface for SDK 11
11-15 14:27:51.225: I/a(29345): Current focus mode 'on'; use auto focus? false
11-15 14:27:51.225: I/Choreographer(29345): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-15 14:27:51.257: D/e(29345): Calculated framing rect: Rect(127, 60 - 727, 420)
11-15 14:27:51.530: W/dalvikvm(29345): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a9f300)
11-15 14:27:51.530: E/AndroidRuntime(29345): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-358
11-15 14:27:51.530: E/AndroidRuntime(29345): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=610560 srcPos=610750 dst.length=485460 dstPos=347913 length=899
11-15 14:27:51.530: E/AndroidRuntime(29345):    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
11-15 14:27:51.530: E/AndroidRuntime(29345):    at com.google.zxing.m.a(Unknown Source)
11-15 14:27:51.530: E/AndroidRuntime(29345):    at com.google.zxing.b.j.a(Unknown Source)
11-15 14:27:51.530: E/AndroidRuntime(29345):    at com.google.zxing.c.a(Unknown Source)
11-15 14:27:51.530: E/AndroidRuntime(29345):    at com.google.zxing.g.a.a(Unknown Source)
11-15 14:27:51.530: E/AndroidRuntime(29345):    at com.google.zxing.i.b(Unknown Source)
11-15 14:27:51.530: E/AndroidRuntime(29345):    at com.google.zxing.i.a(Unknown Source)
11-15 14:27:51.530: E/AndroidRuntime(29345):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.h.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
11-15 14:27:51.530: E/AndroidRuntime(29345):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-15 14:27:51.530: E/AndroidRuntime(29345):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-15 14:27:51.530: E/AndroidRuntime(29345):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.i.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea what is couse of that error? In one example I saw that my activity should extends ActivityCapture insted of Activity but if I do so eclipse mark that as an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to add zxing as library to my android app

The ZXing team does not support this, last I checked.

> it must be offline so using Intent to outside app is bad as many people wouldn't have bar code scanner

Presumably, they are online when they install your app. Hence, presumably they can be online when they install Barcode Scanner.

> and in my app "IntentIntegrator" and "IntentResult" + core.jar added.

`IntentIntegrator` is for integrating with the *Barcode Scanner app*. You said that you do not want to integrate with the Barcode Scanner app.

> After pressing it show messege to install Barcode reader (form google play) - what I'm doing wrong?

You are using `IntentIntegrator`, which is attempting to integrate with the Barcode Scanner app.

> Any idea what is couse of that error?

That would appear to be a problem in the Barcode Scanner app. Try running Barcode Scanner from the launcher and see if it also crashes. If it does, then there is some incompatibility between Barcode Scanner and your device.

Comment: So is there any offline library to barcodes under Android? Yes application is installed when users are online but it is designed to work at place with very low phone signal. ok, so I messed up with this IntentIntegrator. Just give me 5 min. and I will test barcode stand alone app.

Comment: @Primosz: "So is there any offline library to barcodes under Android?" -- possibly, but I have not gone looking for one.

Comment: You were right. There is problem with barcode scanner app on my phone. Weird as I used it some time ago. Other barcode readers (not zxing) works with no problem.

Comment: @Primosz: You might consider filing an issue for the app bug: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/list

Comment: I have send a crash report so they will get it. But moreover if i start emulator and press button to start barcode (on phone it show up message to install barcode) it do nothing. just open new activity (same as that one which was called from)

Comment: Yes I received the crash log. This is a device bug, it seems. It is not sending a YUV image whose size matches what it says it is sending.

Comment: May be fault of CM10-20121109 Android 4.1.2 as I update it few days ago - before for sure it was working. Glad to see that you react so fast :)

Comment: @Primosz [Red Laser](http://www.redlaser.com/) and [SocketScan](http://www.socketmobile.com/support/Developer/Socketscan/) are barcode scanning libraries you can include in your app

Comment: Thanks so much, 25 scans is on the edge of that what app would be for but any way I will give a try.